# How to update a checkboxInput using updateSelectInput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to load historical Shiny inputs and it works great for all input types except `checkboxInput`.  When it executes the `updateSelectInput` command for a checkbox, it does not set it up properly.  Specifically, when I'm trying to update the checkbox with the value `FALSE`, it sets the value to `TRUE`.

To use the code, leave the checkbox blank and click on the **Save Inputs** button to create the file "inputs.RDS". This file contains the name of the input and its value.  Then, click the **Browse** button and load the file "inputs.RDS".  Then click the **Load Inputs** button and the checkbox gets checked, as if the value passed by `updateSelectInput` is `TRUE`.  Here's my code:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI
ui <- (fluidPage
        (
        fileInput("sessionFileName", "Session File Name"),
        actionButton("loadInputs", "Load Inputs"),
        actionButton("saveInputs", "Save Inputs"),
        # Inputs
        sidebarPanel(
          checkboxInput(inputId = "checkbox",label="Checkbox",value=FALSE),
          width=3
          )
        )
      )

# Define server logic
server <- (function(input, output, session)
{
  
  getInputs <- function (sessionFileName) {
    print (paste('getInputs session file name is',sessionFileName,sep=' '))
    if (is.null(sessionFileName)) return ()
    inFile <- sessionFileName
    if (!is.null(inFile)) {
      print ('inFile')
      inputData <- readRDS(file=inFile$name)
    }
    else return ()
    print (inputData)
    for (i in 1:length(inputData)) {
      if (names(inputData[i]) == 'sessionFileName') next
      if (names(inputData[i]) == 'saveInputs') next
      if (names(inputData[i]) == 'loadInputs') next
      print (paste(names(inputData[i]),inputData[[i]],sep=' '))
      updateSelectInput(session=session, inputId=names(inputData[i]), selected=inputData[[i]])
    }
    return ()
  }
  
  observeEvent (input$saveInputs, {
    inputValues <- lapply(reactiveValuesToList(input), unclass)
    saveRDS( inputValues , file = 'inputs.RDS')
  })

  observeEvent (input$loadInputs, {
    print (paste('Session file name is',input$sessionFileName,sep=' '))
    getInputs (input$sessionFileName)
  })
})
  
# Start the shiny app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I examined `typeof` for the checkbox value I'm trying to load and it's a logical, which is what I expect.  Any ideas for solving this problem?

Answer (score 3):

> When it executes the updateSelectInput command for a checkbox, it does not set it up properly

That is your problem.  `updateSelectInput` updates `selectInput`s.  `updateCheckboxInput` unsurprisngly updates `checkbox`s.